# RewriteCond не видит файлы с urlencode-символами

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .phtml .html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index3.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

Данный код прекрасно работал на одном хостинге и хромает на другом: если в имени файла присутствует закодированный пробел %20 или любой другой подобный символ, то RewriteCond считает, что файла не существует, если же заменить в имени файла %20 на " " Mod_Rewrite отрабатывает как надо. Как заставить Mod_Rewrite видеть имена файлов с %20 и другими закодированными символами, желательно посредством .htaccess ?

Comment: вообще-то декодирование *urlencoded*-символов перед подстановкой их в переменную `REQUEST_FILENAME` — это обычное и нормальное поведение *apache*. так что вопрос скорее, должен звучать так: почему это «отлично работало на одном хостинге»? возможно, там использовалась какая экзотическая специально изменённая версия *apache*.

Comment: просто в качестве гипотезы: а вы не пробовали в вашем *rewritecond* заменить переменную `REQUEST_FILENAME` на переменную `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос наименованием OC на рабочем и не рабочем вариантах, версиями апачей, разницей в модулях подключенных к апачам.

Comment: Замена REQUEST_FILENAME на REQUEST_URI проблему не решила

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в начале .htaccess кодировку по умолчанию с помощью команды AddDefaultCharset.
Для UTF-8 например так:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: Кодировка задана